# Bounded ReLU at 1 if x>1?

Tags: machine-learning

Is there a closed form solution for a ReLU that is bounded with a maximum value at 1?
I am trying to produce output values for pixel intensities 0 <= x <= 1, but my outputs are producing values greater than 1. How can I counteract this?

Comment: Are you using a specific framework? Many will allow you to define your own transfer functions (e.g. this should be straightforward to add in TensorFlow)

Comment: "Is there a closed form solution for a ReLU that is bounded with a maximum value at 1?" - closed form solution of what?

Comment: "I am trying to produce output values for pixel intensities 0 <= x <= 1" - why do you want this?

Answer (score 4):

Being itself a non-linearity, the very advantage of ReLUs is their linear regime, that prevents it from saturating too early.

Having said that, a couple of alternatives for your case are to either clip the output of the ReLUs or to place sigmoid (or tanh, adjusting the output range) after them (or instead of them).

Answer (score 0):

Use a sigmoid or tanh. I think it's pointless to use a clipped ReLU in your case also because, in addition to what @ncasas said, for values less than zero or greater than your clipping threshold (i.e. 1) you would not get a gradient, possibly making learning harder.